# How to set up thread-local accumulators for Java parallel streams that are visible to the main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-local-storage

How do I set up some thread-local storage for each worker thread in the default (common) fork-join pool, and how do I access that TLS from the main thread?

I need to implement the "collector" pattern for Java parallel streams, which is like reduce in MapReduce, but with partial reductions of associative operations grouped within each thread, prior to one final reduction step at the end. (Note that I do not want to use the MapReduce pattern directly, for performance reasons -- collectors cut down on the amount of data sent from mappers to reducers.)

Basically I need each thread in the common fork-join thread pool to have a large array of accumulators associated with it, and as the mappers run using `Stream.parallel().forEach(...)`, each thread should collect the resulting value by updating some bin in its own accumulator in a lock-free way. At the end of the operation, I want the calling thread (the main thread) to have access to the accumulators from each worker thread, so that it can do a final reduce to combine all the accumulators into a single accumulator array.

My idea is to use a `ConcurrentSkipListMap` indexed by thread name to store each of the thread-local accumulators, but there is quite a lot of overhead to this, so it's not ideal.

Comment: Have you checked out [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)? Here's a guide: [An Introduction to ThreadLocal](https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal). It might be a useful tool here.

Comment: Yes, I know about `ThreadLocal`. But I need to fetch all `ThreadLocal` values from all threads once the stream ends and passes control back to the main thread. Hence the question.

Comment: @LukeHutchison create an instance of synchronized or thread-safe collection (e.g. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`) outside of the stream, inside the stream put a wrapper (e.g. `AtomicReference`) inside `ThreadLocal` and add this instance of a wrapper to that collection.